# Mule ESB testing applications

Tags: json, user-interface, mule, esb

Normally when I use Mule ESB, I test using the curl program, as follows:

```
C:\curl>type input.txt
{ "creditcardnumber" : "5555222233334444" }

C:\curl>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i -d @input.txt http://localho
st:8081/mule/getBalance
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 21 Jul 2014 11:34:40 -0700
Server: Mule EE Core Extensions/3.5.0
Content-Type: application/json
X-MULE_SESSION: rO0ABXNyACNvcmcubXVsZS5zZXNzaW9uLkRlZmF1bHRNdWxlU2Vzc2lvbi7rdtEW
7GGKAwAFWgAFdmFsaWRMAA1mbG93Q29uc3RydWN0dAAmTG9yZy9tdWxlL2FwaS9jb25zdHJ1Y3QvRmxv
d0NvbnN0cnVjdDtMAAJpZHQAEkxqYXZhL2xhbmcvU3RyaW5nO0wACnByb3BlcnRpZXN0AA9MamF2YS91
dGlsL01hcDtMAA9zZWN1cml0eUNvbnRleHR0ACdMb3JnL211bGUvYXBpL3NlY3VyaXR5L1NlY3VyaXR5
Q29udGV4dDt4cAFwdAAkYWQ0ZWY4YTEtMTEwNS0xMWU0LThiN2EtMDAyMTVlNmIzZDkwc3IAJWphdmEu
dXRpbC5Db2xsZWN0aW9ucyRTeW5jaHJvbml6ZWRNYXAbc/kJS0s5ewMAAkwAAW1xAH4AA0wABW11dGV4
dAASTGphdmEvbGFuZy9PYmplY3Q7eHBzcgAkb3JnLm11bGUudXRpbC5DYXNlSW5zZW5zaXRpdmVIYXNo
TWFwndHZ72dFzgADAAB4cHcMP0AAAAAAABAAAAAAeHEAfgAJeHB4
X-MULE_ENCODING: UTF-8
Content-Length: 15
Connection: close

Default case...
```

What I would like is to use a Mule GUI to test my apps with

Does either Mule ESB or Eclipse provide a HTTP test tool that can send JSON data.  If so what path do I take to find such a tool.

I would appreciate a response even if the tool does not exist, s I know to stop hunting for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOAPui Eclipse plug-in allows testing REST APIs: http://www.soapui.org/IDE-Plugins/eclipse-plugin.html

The good thing is that you can also execute the tests from your Maven build.

Answer (score 0):

Please use postman for testing JSON/Rest. This is just plug in for Chrome and this is the best one available.  Here is the link provided.

https://www.getpostman.com/